# decimal range in for

Tags: python, range

Sorry for my beginner question. I want to construct decimal range step in for cycle using the following construction:

```
max_value = 10
my_range = [r * 0.01 for r in range(0, max_value) ]
    for i in range ( my_range ): //Error
         print (i)
```

But there is the following error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please, give an example of a sequence you'd like to iterate over.

Comment: 2BasicWolf: I updated the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `my_range` is already a list.  Just do:

```
for i in my_range:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because `range()` function accepts three arguments: starting value (included in iteration), end value (not included) and a step. From mathematical point of view, it's: `[a1, a2, ... an)` where `d = a2 - a1` is the step.

So, `my_range = [r * 0.01 for r in range(0, max_value) ]` creates a list. And naturally, `range()` can't accept a list as an argument.

In case, if you need [0.01, 0.02, ... 10]:

```
step = 0.01
max_val = 10
for i in range(0, max_val / step + 1):
    print i * step
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in my_range:
  print(i)
```

You've create the `my_range` list, which you can iterate over with `for`. You don't need to call `range()` again.

The `range()` function accepts integers as parameters, but running `range(my_range)` passes in your list, which results in this error.